# Why cannot use findOne() function in scripts?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

```
<button class="button is-link" type="submit"
                                onclick="matching('<%= product.id %>')">Define</button>
```

The HTML of the button.

```
<script>
    async function matching(productID) {
        var r = confirm("Define preference?");

        if (r) {
            alert("testing1")
            
            var thatProduct = await PriceTracker.findOne(productID);
            
            alert("testing2")

            if (thatProduct) {
                alert("Have that product");
                location.assign("/");
            } else if (response.status == 409) {
                var e = await response.json();
                alert(e);
            } else if (response.status == 404) {
                var e = await response.json();
                alert(e);
            }
        } else {
            alert(response.statusText);
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the code for a matching function with the sails framework.

When I click a button, the matching function will be called.

The confirm box can be displayed. When I click 'ok', the alert message of "testing1" can also be displayed, while the second alert message "testing2" could not display, and hence the "if condition" cannot be reached as well.

How can I get that product from my database for further usage?

Comment: check your console. I have no idea what `PriceTracker.findOne` does (and you don't show us the implementation), but that must either be throwing an error, or be an asynchronous call that never completes (or at least doesn't complete in the time you're waiting for it). If it makes a network request, check the network tab for what's happening.

Comment: PriceTracker is a controller for the api. And findOne is a internal function of sails (https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await won’t work in the top-level code

Change your `matching` function into this

> ```
> var matching = (async (productID) => {
>     try {
>        ...    } 
>     catch (e) {
>       // handle the error
>       ...
>     }
> })();
> ```

Comment: I got it. So, I change to fetch for a route

Comment: I changed to fetch for a route and that route return a res.json of that product. However, I want to get the title of the product by "thatProduct.title", it says "undefined".

Comment: So, how can I get the attributes of that product? Thank you.

Comment: have you parse your response to json yet ?

Comment: Yes. I have returned by res.json(object). And I have changed the return to json by JSON.stringify(object) as well. But when I tried print out the json.title, it outputed undefined.

Comment: JSON.stringify is used for converting json to string

Comment: I have used the parse(object) function to parse my response to json. But it output undefined as well

Comment: Can you create a sandbox, that would be easier for me to help you